# Clojure server configuration for SPA's with client-side routing

Tags: clojurescript, ring, reagent, boot-clj, re-frame

I'm working on a ClojureScript Single-Page app with routing on client-side. I'd like to implement a simple server with would serve my index.html as well as CSS/JS. The idea is to pass all requests apart from /static/* down to client-side and allow my SPA to deal with it.

It turned out to be surprisingly difficult. The snippet below is something I came up, but it doesn't work.

```
(defroutes routes
  (GET "/" []
    (resp/content-type template "text/html"))
  (context "/static" []
    (route/resources "/css" {:root "css"})
    (route/resources "/js" {:root "js"}))
  (route/not-found
    (resp/content-type template "text/html")))
```

I use boot-http with custom handler. Any chance it could cause it?

Comment: It's hard to help when you haven't provided information how your project layout looks like, your `build.boot` file and what the error you are getting. Could you please add more information to your question?

Comment: thanks for the reply! actually, I don't think it relevant here... can't see anything boot specific here... just 3 files to serve

Comment: So what do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you don't need a backend at all; you can develop with boot-http/boot-reload and deploy to gh-pages, firebase, aws or any static file host. See https://github.com/martinklepsch/tenzing for a template project #nobackend.

Comment: You still need a custom handler for the boot-http's `serve` command. It doesn't support SPA with client side routing by default (visiting http://localhost:3000/some/page would 404).